# Implement Idisposable on mvc3 controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, controller, dispose

I have a controller that instantiates a database context for EF. (As I'm sure most that aren't implementing the repository pattern do.)

When I ran code analysis on my project it recommended implementing IDisposable so I wrote the following code.

```
    #region Implementation of IDisposable
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Dispose");
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    // The bulk of the clean-up code is implemented in Dispose(bool)
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Dispose(disposing)");
        if (disposing)
        {
            // free managed resources
            if (_dataService != null)
            {
                ((IDisposable)_dataService).Dispose();
                _dataService = null;
            }
            // free managed resources
            if (_db != null)
            {
                ((IDisposable)_db).Dispose();
                _db = null;
            }

        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);

    }
    #endregion
```

I've also tried doing.

```
protected new virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
```

But my console.writeline statements never execute.  What am I doing wrong?  Why isn't Dispose() being called on my controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't do anything wrong. You get the recommentation because you hold some fields in your class (cotnroller) that implements IDisposable. The framework will call the "overload"-version so just move all your code in there.

[Details on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492699.aspx)

BTW you won't see the console-writeline - use System.Diagnostic.Debug.WriteLine instead

Comment: Console.WriteLine prints something on the console - in an MVC-app there (should) be no Console (or better: Console.Out should be null/not set I think) - with Debug.WriteLine you can allways print something into the Debug-Window

Answer (score 2):

Personally I think the best thing to do in this situation is to split out the database context away from the controller and move it to a service layer. You can them make that class implement IDisposable and pass the reference to the service layer class to the controller to use it

In doing this you will create a controller that is not dependant on the database. The term skinny controllers, fat models applies here. the service layer will act as a model in this instance. You can also unit test the service layer and controller (if you want) in isolation from each other

Comment: Yes, I am transitioning to a repository pattern now.  The simplicity of testing far outweighs the cost of the layer of indirection in the repository pattern.